# Parent property change detection after child changes its two-way-bound property

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I have a custom implemented banana in a box, from parent to child. Somehow the properties get updated fine in both parent and child, but I can't catch the moment when this property changes in parent. I need this moment because I want to do something on it. How do I do it? Here is some code from parent:

```
<child
    [(optionList)]="countriesList"
    (optionListChange)="countriesListChanged()">
</child>
```

From child:

```
    _optionList: Array<CustomSelectOption> = [];

    @Output()
    optionListChange = new EventEmitter<CustomSelectOption[]>();

    @Input()
    get optionList() {
        return this._optionList;
    }
    set optionList(val) {
        this._optionList = val;
        this.optionListChange.emit(this._optionList);
    }
```

So the `(optionListChange)` (child's event) and, consequently, 
 the handler method `countriesListChanged()` (of the parent) never get triggered, although I am changing this in the child component (it changes during the use of the child component in the browser).

Comment: " I can't catch the moment when this property" what is the property you are talking about here? And who changing the property? child-component by (output)?

Comment: how about placing `@Input()` decorator above setter `set optionList(val)`

Comment: I am talking about child's property optionList. Yes, the moment I am talking about is the moment in which this property is changed in child. But I need to handle this change in parent - because there is the bound property in parent for this too , its name is countriesList.

Comment: @ysf that didn't work, I tried it.

Comment: have you tried catching changes in `ngOnChanges` hook?

Comment: I tried that too. Didn't work. I have to initiate manually the this.optionListChange.emit by catching it where it happens. It wouldn't happen automatically.

Comment: How do you change `optionList` in the parent component? Is the `optionList` setter triggered (you can check with a `console.log` statement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure whether you want to catch changes to `countriesList` in parent or `optionList` in child so i created a demo that handles both cases.

you can see it in action here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svbvh1

changes made in child propogated to parent as follows in child.ts

```js
  addCountry() {
    this.optionList.push("child-added-country" + (this.optionList.length + 1));
    this.optionListChange.emit(this.optionList);
  }
```

changes coming from parent are propogated as follows in child.ts

```js
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.optionList) {
      this.optionListChange.emit(changes.optionList.currentValue);
    }
  }
```

and they both are caught in parent as follows

```js
  countriesListChanged(list: string[]) {
    console.log("countriesListChanged: ", list);
    console.log("countriesList in parent: ", this.countriesList);
  }
```

Comment: I want to catch it in parent.

Comment: in the demo i added above both changes are caught in parent and printed to console

Answer (score 0):

Try this, little old school

parent.html

```
<child
    [optionList]="countriesList"
    (optionListChange)="countriesListChanged($event)">
</child>
```

child.ts

```
@Output()
optionListChange = new EventEmitter<CustomSelectOption[]>();

@Input() optionList: CustomSelectOption[];

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.optionList); // list coming from parent
}

// list changed by the child, letting know the parent
changeOptionList(val: CustomSelectOption[]) {
    this.optionList = val;
    this.optionListChange.emit(this.optionList);
}
```

parent.ts

```
countriesListChanged(event: CustomSelectOption[]) {
    console.log('coming from child', event)
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, the changeOptionList is never triggered in child.

Comment: Its need to be trigger by user action, when u do something in the child then you change the state of the `optionList` . Unless you already have the state in parent when you render the child `[optionList]="countriesList"`?